# Where is this VSCODE intellisense coming from?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, javascript-intellisense

In VSCODE I see the following intellisense:

[image]

When exploring `node_modules/sanctuary/index.js`, I find a function `toMaybe`, but it doesn't appear the definition is coming from here because they do not match

````
//# toMaybe :: a? -> Maybe a
//.
//. Takes a value and returns Nothing if the value is `null` or `undefined`;
//. Just the value otherwise.
//.
//. ```javascript
//. > S.toMaybe (null)
//. Nothing
//.
//. > S.toMaybe (42)
//. Just (42)
//. ```
````

This is in contrast to other functions that commonly display like this:

[image]

Two questions:

1. Where should I look next?
2. How can I document my own functions like this?

UPDATE:

Lukas Bach and ippi have pointed out, one part, `Sanctuary.Static.toMaybe<A>(p: A): Maybe<A>` comes from the Automatic type acquisition feature.

Even after deleting all `@types` from `~/Library/Caches/typescript/2.9/node_modules/types-registry`, I still see some docs.

[image]

I also was not able to find the text `toMaybe :: a -> Maybe a` in the `@types/sanctuary/index.d.ts` file or anywhere in the `@types` directory.

Answer (score 2):

The programming language TypeScript, a superset of JavaScript, allows definitions for proper types on functions and variables. TypeScript can be compiled down to JavaScript, which removes all type annotations, and a seperate type definition file (*.d.ts) can be exported during transpiliation. TypeScript type definitions are nowadays commonly provided for JS modules either directly in the module repository itself or as part of the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository.

To get such type annotations for your own code, you can either write your code in TypeScript in the first place or write additional custom type definition files by yourself.

This is not the only way to write type definitions, but at the moment the most prominent one.

Edit: Ok, I did not really look into the package that you've mentioned earlier. But I've tried it out, and this is the IntelliSense annotation, which it gives to me.[image: VS Screenshot]

And this seems to be coming from the TS typing:

`toMaybe<A>(p: A | null | undefined): Maybe<A>;`

These typings are located at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sanctuary.

Comment: I considered this, I wasn't able to find any references to TypeScript definitions within the sanctuary project. I'm trying to trace the path from intellisense to the file that contains the docs so that I may learn how vscode is creating this.

Comment: *Automatic type acquisition* in vs-code. You can ctrl-click (or alt dending on settings) on `toMaybe` in vs code (or place cursor and click F12) and it jumps directly to the declaration, in this case the type-definition file: [sanctuary/index.d.ts#L197](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sanctuary/index.d.ts#L197)  or locally: :`%localappdata%\Microsoft\TypeScript\2.9\node_modules\@types\sanctuary\index.d.ts`(on windows).

If you use an npm-package and there is a matching @types/packagename for it, it will be installed and used.

Comment: @types are installed even if the type-definitions are old and doesn't match (which probably is your problem here seeing how the declaration file is from March but sanctuary-maybe was updated May). This is actually disappointingly common, but the reason is often that the projects doesn't use types to begin with and/or types has been added by some third party.

Comment: Automatic Type Acquisition makes sense. I have F12 to the Definition `@types/sanctuary` in the global `node_modules`, which contains `toMaybe<A>(p: A | null | undefined): Maybe<A>;` (half of what I am looking for) but doesn't contain `toMaybe :: a -> Maybe a`. I have updated the OP.

Comment: These remaining annotations could be generated by the runtime type-system sanctuary-def (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanctuary-def). It looks like they generate type annotations which look exactly like the haskell-like type annotations that you have described.

Comment: I didn't find a match for `toMaybe` in `sanctuary-def`. I did a `grep -R toMaybe node_modules` and the only match was `node_modules/sanctuary/index.js` and a readme.

Comment: I am not saying that ```sanctuary-def``` contains the type annotation for ```toMaybe```, but that it generates this typing dynamically, as this is that this package is doing to my understanding.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. `sanctuary-def` is generating the annotation for `toMaybe` dynamically. I did some digging through that library and found the solution. The piece I was missing was `inspect`. With source: https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-def/blob/87e1092ebacafc9f9d61a321f51c5329cf17b883/index.js, you need line 214 `inspect` function. Then line 2565 `wrapped[inspect] = wrapped.toString = 'custom name here'`. If you could update your answer with this code, I'll mark it as the Solution. Thanks!